# Counterexample for limsup

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

Statement: $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n a_n = c \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$

Please help find a counterexample to this statement if $c<0$.

Edit: also suppose $c_n \to c$ and $\limsup a_n$ is finite

Comment: Are you supposing that $\lim c_n$ does exist and it's equal to $c$?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @kiwifruit The limit superior or the ordinary limit?

Comment: The ordinary limit of $c_n$ is c

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the statement true if we have $c\ge 0$?

Comment: I have not proved it, but there is also a question to prove it if $c \ge 0$. So I think yes

Comment: Interesting... well good luck! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c_n = -1 \to -1 = c $, and $a_n = (-1)^n$. then

$$ limsup (c_na_n) = 1$$

$$ -1 ( \limsup(a_n) ) = -1 $$

Answer (score 1):

$c_n\equiv-1$, $a_n=\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{6}\right)$.

Then $\limsup(c_na_n)=1$ but $\limsup a_n=1$ too hence $-\limsup a_n=-1\neq\limsup(c_na_n)=1$.